# How to apply different styles in different screen sizes in antd react?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I have used material-ui for some of my prev projects and know i want to use antd.
In material-ui we can apply different styles for a div in different screen sizes,

```
const styles = theme => ({
    main: {
        [theme.breakpoints.only('md')]: {
            height: '360px',
        },
        [theme.breakpoints.only('sm')]: {
            height: '280px',
        }
    }
});
```

How we can accomplish that in antd?

Answer (score 0):

AntD uses ordinary CSS or LESS to accomplish this, which means you can't use inline styles as in your question unless you use some 3rd party styling plugin.

[The AntD default theme](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/blob/master/components/style/themes/default.less) provides the breakpoint variables:

```
@screen-xs              : 480px;
@screen-sm              : 576px;
@screen-md              : 768px;
@screen-lg              : 992px;
@screen-xl              : 1200px;
@screen-xxl             : 1600px;
```

These can then be used in LESS files for standard media queries.